# How generate automatic filename

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-type

I would like to name the documents in the document library based on meta tags and the document ID sharepoint give the document. Is there any way to achieve this without using sharepoint designer?

Comment: I would recommend to use MS Flow.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Ram. I have tried to set up a flow that kicks in when someone add a document to the library, but can't quite figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no way to do this with Flow due to Microsoft flow doesn’t support to update file name.

The solution was therefore just to make a calculated field that "generated" the filename, and use sharepoint designer to make a workflow like this:
Set Name to Current Item:CalcualtedField.